# VS2013 AddIn into VS2015 VSPackage: How can I create ToolWindow2

Tags: add-in, vsix, vspackage

Can anyone please guide me how can I convert Add-Ins to VSPackage Extention without recreating/replicating everything into VSIX?

I have one addin which is supporting VS2010 to VS2013. I have everything in .sln. I want to migrate/create .addin into .vsix for compatibility issue of VS2015. After few research, I have found that the code what is written in IDTCommandTarget.Exec method has to run into my custom command class of vsix project...

So, I created a new .vsix project in same solution & add a reference of my .addin project into .vsix project and I am able to load initial controls of my addin project as like below...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhdI3.png)

but as per the code, I want to create CreateToolWindow2 on double click of my tree node but I am getting following error (null AddInInstance)...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg74X.png)

Can anyone please guide me how can I create an Instance of AddIn class to create ToolWindow2?

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite the way to do this. You create a .VSIX project, then add a Custom Command, and you add the code/logic that was in your old addin's Exec method, to the custom commands MenuItemCallback method.

Note, you no longer need to programmatically create the menus/commands, toolbars, etc. VSPackages have an entirely different (and much more effective way) via the .VSCT file.

[FAQ: Converting Add-ins to VSPackage Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246938(v=vs.140).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To convert an add-in to a package is not easy or trivial, you need to use .vsct file to create menus, toolbars, commands, etc.

About toolwindows:

The usual way for packages is:

HOWTO: Create a toolwindow with a ToolWindowPane class in a Visual Studio package
http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages/

But you can do it in the same way as add-ins:
HOWTO: Create a toolwindow without a ToolWindowPane class in a Visual Studio package
(same link)

About not "duplicating everything" when migrating an add-in to a package, see my post:

[Strategies migrating from Visual Studio add-ins to packages](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2014/07/01/strategies-migrating-from-visual-studio-add-ins-to-packages/)